# position android buttons on absolute view became nested buttons. only 1 btn shows

Tags: java, android

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/asdasd"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <!--    -->


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG7"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="asdasdasd"
        tools:layout_x="124dp"
        tools:layout_y="317dp"
        ></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="10dp"
        tools:layout_y="144dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="10dp"
        tools:layout_y="180dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGs"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="10dp"
        tools:layout_y="215dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDs"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="10dp"
        tools:layout_y="250dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAs"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="10dp"
        tools:layout_y="285dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF6"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="10dp"
        tools:layout_y="315dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="124dp"
        tools:layout_y="144dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="124dp"

        tools:layout_y="179dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF5"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="124dp"

        tools:layout_y="247dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC5"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="124dp"

        tools:layout_y="282dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAs5"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="124dp"

        tools:layout_y="212dp"></Button>

    <!---->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="236dp"
        tools:layout_y="144dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonE"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="236dp"

        tools:layout_y="179dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="236dp"

        tools:layout_y="212dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="236dp"

        tools:layout_y="282dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="236dp"

        tools:layout_y="317dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="236dp"

        tools:layout_y="247dp"></Button>

<!--    -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonB"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="351dp"
        tools:layout_y="144dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD3"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="351dp"

        tools:layout_y="212dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA3"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="351dp"

        tools:layout_y="247dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonE2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="351dp"

        tools:layout_y="282dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonB2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="351dp"

        tools:layout_y="317dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFs"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="351dp"

        tools:layout_y="179dp"></Button>
<!---->


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC3"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="471dp"
        tools:layout_y="144dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG3"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="471dp"

        tools:layout_y="179dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAs2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="471dp"

        tools:layout_y="247dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="471dp"

        tools:layout_y="282dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC4"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="471dp"

        tools:layout_y="317dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDs2"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="471dp"

        tools:layout_y="212dp"></Button>
<!---->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD4"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="604dp"
        tools:layout_y="144dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF3"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="212dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG4"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="282dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD7"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="317dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAs4"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="247dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA4"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="179dp"></Button>
<!---->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD5"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="604dp"
        tools:layout_y="144dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF4"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="212dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG6"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="282dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD8"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="317dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAs3"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="247dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA6"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="604dp"

        tools:layout_y="179dp"></Button>
<!--    -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonE3"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"

        tools:layout_x="713dp"
        tools:layout_y="144dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonB3"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="713dp"

        tools:layout_y="179dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD6"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="713dp"

        tools:layout_y="247dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA5"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="713dp"

        tools:layout_y="282dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonE4"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="713dp"

        tools:layout_y="317dp"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG5"

        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        tools:layout_x="713dp"

        tools:layout_y="212dp"></Button>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

when i build this code,

app will open on landscape mode.

but all of my buttons are nesting

and it shows only 1 btn

how can i solve it?

i had tried by constraint view, but it was same.

this is my github

https://github.com/sksmsWKd/2021android-backup/commit/cb6bb1774b3f8307f211ed6feb16eab0a9bf3620

i pushed this code today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutFirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/constraintLayoutSecond">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn3" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutSecond"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/constraintLayoutFirst"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/constraintLayoutThirst"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn7" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutThirst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/constraintLayoutSecond"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/constraintLayoutFour"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn10"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn12"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn11" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/constraintLayoutThirst"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn14"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn13"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn15" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn16"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn14" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn15" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Set layout in landscape:

```
<activity
    android:name="YourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, you should't use this and if you want to move button you can use margin as:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn16"
        ...
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
```

instead of:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn16"
        ...
        tools:layout_x="10dp"
        tools:layout_y="10dp"/>
```